Increment last number in string contained in spreadsheet cell
I am trying to create a formula that is compatible with both MS Excel and LibreOffice Calc. The formula is to be copied across multiple columns and increments the last number of a string in the cell of the previous column.
Consider the following inputs for cell A1:

host1
host01
host1-ilo
host01-idrac
dc1-host1
dc1host01
dc1-host1-ilo
dc01host01-idrac

For the use cases above, the formula in cell B1 should evaluate to the following:

host2
host02
host2-ilo
host02-idrac
dc1-host2
dc1host02
dc1-host2-ilo
dc01host02-idrac

I think the key is to isolate the last number(s) in the string, add 1 and then possibly add leading zeros to the result. Finally, place that back into the original string.
So far, I have the following array formula to isolate the number, but that doesn't work for the last four example inputs as it takes all numbers into account:
=IFERROR(IF(COUNT(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>LEN(TEXTJOIN("",1,IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)+0,""))),"", TEXT(VALUE(TEXTJOIN("",1,IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)+0,"")))+1,REPT("0",LEN(TEXTJOIN("",1,IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)+0,"")))))),"")


How do you want carries to be handled, e.g. should "host9" and "host09" both become "host10"?

Does the substring host actually exist in all of the possible values, or are you just using that as a placeholder?

"host9" and "host09" should both become "host10". The substring "host" could be anything. Instead of "host" it could say "sql" or "prd-sql" or "websrv", etc.

A quick attempt, LAMBDA, MAP and SEQUENCE may not be available - please let me know.
=LET(
    incr_last_num, LAMBDA(input, incr,
        LET(
            input_index, SEQUENCE(, LEN(input)),
            index_last_digit, MAX(
                ISNUMBER(--MID(input, input_index, 1)) * input_index
            ),
            right_of_num, RIGHT(input, LEN(input) - index_last_digit),
            left, LEFT(input, index_last_digit),
            _left_index, SEQUENCE(, LEN(left)),
            index_last_non_digit, MAX(
                NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(input, _left_index, 1))) * _left_index
            ),
            num, RIGHT(left, LEN(left) - index_last_non_digit),
            left_of_num, LEFT(left, index_last_non_digit),
            left_of_num & TEXT(num + incr, REPT("0", LEN(num))) &
                right_of_num
        )
    ),
    first_col, A1:A8,
    result, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "Build columns with incremented numbers",
            SEQUENCE(2),
            LAMBDA(acc, incr,
                HSTACK(
                    acc,
                    MAP(first_col, LAMBDA(c, incr_last_num(c, incr)))
                )
            )
        ),
        ,
        1
    ),
    result
)



Excel 2021+, Applying Name
If MAP etc. are not available, you could define a name and fill down.
Here's an example:

With input range A1:A8, select B1
Define IncrementLastNumber in Name Manager - using relative reference A1


=LET(
    input, A1,
    input_index, SEQUENCE(, LEN(input)),
    index_last_digit, MAX(
        ISNUMBER(--MID(input, SEQUENCE(, LEN(input)), 1)) *
            SEQUENCE(, LEN(input))
    ),
    left, LEFT(input, index_last_digit),
    _left_index, SEQUENCE(, LEN(left)),
    index_last_non_digit, MAX(
        NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(input, _left_index, 1))) * _left_index
    ),
    num, RIGHT(left, LEN(left) - index_last_non_digit),
    LEFT(left, index_last_non_digit) & TEXT(num + 1, REPT("0", LEN(num))) &
        RIGHT(input, LEN(input) - index_last_digit)
)


Select B1 (since we defined the name with A1)
Enter =incrementLastNumber
Fill down and then right


REGEX
Using regex from Marc's comment (in Mac Microsoft 365, insider's):
=LET(
    host, A1:A8,
    re_last_num, "\d+(?!.*\d)",
    last_num, REGEXEXTRACT(host, re_last_num),
    REGEXREPLACE(host, re_last_num, TEXT(last_num + 1, REPT("0", LEN(last_num))))
)



Wow, that is quite something. You are right, this will not work in LibreOffice Calc. I made the formula that does work in Calc:

Wow, that is quite something. You are right, this will not work in LibreOffice Calc. I made the formula that works in Calc:
=REGEX(A1,"(\d+)(?!.*\d)",TEXT(VALUE(REGEX(A1,"(\d+)(?!.*\d)")) + 1,REPT("0",LEN(REGEX(A1,"(\d+)(?!.*\d)")))))
I was thinking about doing something like =iferror(LOcalc formula,MSexcel formula) that way it should work for both LibreOffice Calc and MS Excel. Unfortunately, when I do so and I open it, Excel complains about a problem with the content and removes the formula.

Thank you for testing and kind feedback @Marc! BTW, I love regex :) I haven't used LibreOffice, I'll install and take a look. Regex is almost available in Excel, but with different function names; please take a look when you have time: https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/new-regular-expression-regex-functions-in-excel

Tested in LibreOffice - very nice regex @Marc! Updated the answer to include in it.

I had seen the new regex formulas coming to Excel, but I don't have access yet. I tried to combine your Excel 2021+ solution with my regex in an =iferror(). LO Calc honours this without any problems, however MS Excel turns the formulas into garbage. I will revisit this once the regex functionality becomes generally available to MS Excel. @nkalvi Thanks for your input!
